# an option or extension to export changes made to the document

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have enabled track changes and changed 2 words as seen in this screenshot.

atest > test
trac > track

Can I save this list of 2 lines in a csv or .txt file? I do not see "export changes" option anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **menu** (option or extension): no, not that I know of. But with a tool? In theory that would be perfectly possible.

You can open the ODT file as a ZIP file. This allows access to the `content.xml` sub-file, where changes are stored in the `<text:tracked-changes>` XML node.

In each "changed-region" you will find whether it is an insert, a deletion, and who and when did it, together with an ID that maps to a `<text:change-end text:change-id="ctUNIXTIME_IN_SECONDS"/>` node inside the text itself (not so useful for tracking).

If you apply the changes in timestamp order, that's the "accept all changes" algorithm.

I believe you could actually get a CSV object from the XML file with the appropriate XSLT directives.

```
            <text:p text:style-name="P2">
                <text:span text:style-name="T1">Seconda</text:span>
            </text:p>
        </text:deletion>
    </text:changed-region>
    <text:changed-region xml:id="ct1526650030752" text:id="ct1526650030752">
        <text:insertion>
            <office:change-info>
                <dc:creator>Leonardo Serni</dc:creator>
                <dc:date>2021-01-18T00:44:08</dc:date>
            </office:change-info>
        </text:insertion>
    </text:changed-region>
    <text:changed-region xml:id="ct1526650030272" text:id="ct1526650030272">
         <text:insertion>
              <office:change-info>
                  <dc:creator>Raffaello Mascetti</dc:creator>
                  <dc:date>2021-01-18T00:44:02</dc:date>
              </office:change-info>
         </text:insertion>
    </text:changed-region>
</text:tracked-changes>

<text:p text:style-name="P2">
    <text:change text:change-id="ct1526650030512"/>
    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct1526650030752"/>
    <text:span text:style-name="T3">Terza</text:span>
    <text:change-end text:change-id="ct1526650030752"/>
    <text:span text:style-name="T2"> modifica.</text:span>
    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct1526650030272"/>
</text:p>
<text:p text:style-name="P3">Ancora.
    <text:change-end text:change-id="ct1526650030272"/>
</text:p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct, you cant export only the changes, what you can do (using LibreOffice) is to export a pdf that includes the changes:

`Edit > Changes > Show Changes?`

`File > Export As > Export as PDF`

Comment: Where can I request for such a feature/ extension?

Comment: @shantanuo you should have access to that feature already 
check: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/ref_pdf_export.html or https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/196902/how-can-i-save-my-docs-in-pdf/#:~:text=If%20you're%20asking%20how,As%20%2D%2D%3E%20Export%20as%20PDF.

Comment: I am looking for a way to save "only" changed words to a .csv file. saving to PDF is good but not the format suitable for database.

Answer (score 1):

You can export to pdf like this

[image]